# POSIX semaphores in named shared memory behavior

Tags: c, linux, multitasking

I'm using POSIX semaphores in shared memory to synchronize processes, and seeing some strange behavior that I wasn't expecting.  I am unsure if this is *expected* behavior or if I'm perhaps doing something wrong.

Here is the background info:

- Parent process is the "executive", which creates "worker" child processes, although not all at once.
- Workers will pend on a semaphore when idle.  Some other process (executive or another worker) will post the semaphore when there is work to do.  Each worker has its own semaphore in a separate shared memory segment that it waits on.
- Just before starting a new worker process, parent sets up its shared memory segment and initializes the process-shared POSIX semaphore within it.  This is done via `shm_open()`,`ftruncate()`,`mmap()`, and `sem_init()` (with the pshared flag set 1, of course).
- Parent then does the standard `fork()` and `exec()` to run the child process.
- The child process then maps the same shared memory segment, and does a `sem_wait()` on the semaphore within its "worker task" loop.

Up to this point, all this works as expected.  The parent/executive is able to release the worker process by calling `sem_post()` and this works fine.

Here is where the unexpected happens:  At some point later, a second worker is  started.  This second worker will also potentially need to signal the first worker, so it maps *both* memory segments (its own as well as the segment from the first worker).

BUT: **When the second worker calls `sem_post()` on the first worker's sem, the first worker does not get released.**  It never wakes up from its `sem_wait()` call.

HOWEVER: as a debug attempt, I can insert `sleep()` calls to force the second worker to be created (and map the memory) prior to the first worker calling `sem_wait()`.  In this case, **the semaphores work as expected**, releasing the first worker once the second worker does call `sem_post()`.  Not only for the first call, but every transaction thereafter is fine as well.

The only difference between these two transactions is the order of the `mmap()` call and the `sem_wait()`:

In case A, the `sem_wait()` happens first, followed by another process calling `mmap()` and `sem_post()`.

In case B, the `mmap()` happens first (such that both processes mapping to the memory have it mapped in) and followed by `sem_wait()` / `sem_post()`.  This works.

So the question is: Is this expected behavior?
If so, why can't a second process map to and post a semaphore after a first process is already pending on it?

My test system is x86-64 / Ubuntu 16.04 / Linux 4.13.0.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're mapping with `MAP_SHARED` and not `MAP_PRIVATE`? And are you sure you used the process-shared flag when calling `sem_init`? Either mistake might explain the problem.

Comment: Yes to both.  That was the first thing I thought!  As I said, the only thing I change is the introduction of a sleep in the first worker, which is long enough such that the second worker does its `mmap` _before_ the first worker does its `sem_wait`.  This is the only change, otherwise everything is identical.

Comment: It the parent possibly calling `shm_open` with `O_CREAT` twice, thereby deleting the old shm segment and making a new one with the same name?

Comment: I thought of that too, so I added some additional fields in the shared memory that only the worker threads will set, and will set differently.  With this I confirmed that the worker process is indeed looking at the correct shm segment (simple printf of the value before doing the sem post/wait call).  FWIW I am looking at using a signal (i.e. SIGUSR1) instead of a process-shared sem for this, but I'd like to understand why semaphores aren't working like I expect.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with an example small enough to post in full?